# Search XML in powershell with colon

Tags: xml, powershell, xml-namespaces

I have an XML in the format:

```
<val:root>
   <bla>
     <value>1234</value>
</val:root>
```

I can do get-content of the file to an $xml variable, but I'm having trouble with the "val:root".

Thanks for any help!

Edit:

I tried $xml."val:root", $xml.val, $xml.'val:root' and $xml.{val:root}. Found the solution in Mizo's answer:

> $xml.**root**.value

Comment: "but I'm having trouble with the "val:root"" - need more details. What trouble? What are you trying to do? What isn't working? Are there errors? What PS commands are you using? What is the expected behavior? How is the actual behavior different?

Comment: My guess is that you are getting an undeclared namespace error?

Comment: Sorry, should have been more detailed. Added a little more info. Thank you for the help EBGreen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your XML file is missing a declaration for the `val` namespace. Also, the `<bla>` element is unterminated.

- Place a namespace declaration in the `<root>` element:

  ```
  <val:root xmlns:val="urn:dummy">
  ```

  Then you can do

  ```
   PS C:\> $xml = [xml] (get-content test.xml)
   PS C:\Users\mizo\test> $xml.root.value
   1234
  ```
- If you don't have control over the XML data, you can declare the `val` namespace in a dummy root as a workaround:

  ```
  $xml = [xml] ("<dummyroot xmlns:val='urn:dummy'>" +
                (get-content test.xml) +
                "</dummyroot>")
  ```

  Then you can access the elements:

  ```
  PS C:\> $xml.dummyroot.root.value
  1234
  ```

Replace `urn:dummy` with a relevant identifier if you wish.

Comment: This will work, but I think it is solving the wrong problem since the xml would still be malformed if it was attempted to be used for some other purpose.

Comment: @EBGreen, My answer assumed the OP has no control over input XML data, which often is the case. You are right - the best approach is to fix the XML file itself, if possible. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

So I'm going to take a stab at the issue even without all the info. Based on the sample XML that you provided, your XML is malformed. You have at least two issues. The first is the  tag without a matching close tag. The second is that you are using a namespace without declaring it. To address this issue, change this:

```
<val:root>
```

To this:

```
<val:root xmlns:val="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
```

Or use a more appropriate URI if you would prefer.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to define the namespace(s) when you load the XML file.

http://huddledmasses.org/xpath-and-namespaces-in-powershell/